# In Google Sheets, with scripts, how do I only update new records that I get from an API call?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm fetching data every day from an external API to a Google Sheet. The data is ordered by date. There are about 20 new records per day.

When the data is updated, I would like to add any new data as new rows. I add my own notes to the data so it has to be in order. Currently I copy the data to another sheet and then make my notes there.

The problem I'm having is that sometimes there is new data added where the date can be a month back or so. So I always have to fetch around 600 records and there might or might not be new additions somewhere with a past date.

I would like to add this new data automatically as new rows in the sheet.

So, I would have to somehow identify the new records and add them as new rows. Anyone have thoughts on how to do this efficiently?

Seems it's not a good idea to loop through my whole sheet with 1000 rows for every record I get from the API...

Should I be using a database? Or Can I load all the API data and all the Sheet data and quickly just add everything new to the Sheet data?

Comment: "Anyone having thoughts..." and the ending questions makes this question to be primarily opinion-based, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a trigger that will detect row insertions into your spreadsheet.

Those insertions will be captured as onChange() events.

```
function installTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onChange')
    .forSpreadsheet(ss)
    .onChange()
    .create();
}  

function onChange(x) {
  if (x.changeType == "INSERT_ROW") {
    var r = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getRow();
    Logger.log(r);
    //Do something with row r
    //If multiple rows can be inserted at once, you might need to check the height of the range
  }
}
```